# Why "deny from all" doesnt work with another values in .htaccess?

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess

I have this values in .htaccess:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

It works great,
but when I add

```
deny from all
```

it doesn't works,
but works without "ifModule" values.
What I'm doing wrong?

Comment: also, allow from 127.0.0.1 doesnt work

Comment: Did you make sure you have `mod_rewrite` enabled? Also, in some cases either via `apache2.conf`, `httpd.conf`, or your enabled apache site you have to add `AllowOverride All` to the document root in order to enable local `.htaccess` files.